React Query and Next14 build error : No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
Hi I can't build my next14 + react query + ky project. I want to consume a REST API with react query inside my next14 project. It works perfectly in dev mode, but when I try to build I get an error basically saying  :  Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one. I set a QueryClientProvider in layout.tsx file as said here : https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/framework/react/guides/. Here is an OSS reproduction of this bug with details about the issue in the README : https://github.com/Courtcircuits/next14-react-query-error. I've been battling with this for two days and found no solution on StackOverflow or next's github issue
I tried to restart the project from scratch, tried to install different versions of @tanstack/react-query.

Hey Tristan, there are some guidelines on how to craft a good question on Stack Overflow – notably here, it's important that you provide a minimum reproducible example of the problem you're experiencing and the relevant code here. Links out to external sources get stale after a time, and it's hard to troubleshoot that way.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hey @brandonscript, I didn't know about the external link thing, next time I'll provide enough code ! Someone helped me fix the problem ! The issue was that I was using the app router AND the pages router because I wanted to separate my ui from my business logic. Now it's fixed, thanks for your advice

I finally fixed the problem. Actually the problem was not related to react query but to a bad usage of next router. I had two folders :
/app
/pages

My error was that I wanted to put my business logic and ui code in /pages without these files being rendered. I wanted my /app to be the only folder rendered. Therefore be careful when naming your folders in Next, /app and /pages are used by Next !
